export 'Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar') was not found in 'flowbite-react' (possible exports: theme)
When i run our Project using npm start then these error are show
Failed to compile.
Attempted import error: 'Navbar' is not exported from 'flowbite-react' (imported as 'Navbar').
ERROR in ./src/admin/admins.js 48:44-50
export 'Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar') was not found in 'flowbite-react' (possible exports: theme)
ERROR in ./src/admin/admins.js 51:46-58
export 'Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar') was not found in 'flowbite-react' (possible exports: theme)
ERROR in ./src/admin/billing.js 37:44-50
export 'Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar') was not found in 'flowbite-react' (possible exports: theme)
ERROR in ./src/admin/components/adminsidebar.js 63:30-37
export 'Sidebar' (imported as 'Sidebar') was not found in 'flowbite-react' (possible exports: theme)
Errors
I tried to fix Flowbite-react version but it didn't work. Please help me.
